# Indexof() returning -1

Tags: javascript, indexof

Been making a simple form + data validation thing, I'm using indexof to make sure there is a "@" and "." in the email address, but it is always returning -1.

```
var custEmail = document.getElementById("custEmail");
if (custEmail.value == "" || custEmail.value.indexOf("@" == -1) || custEmail.value.indexOf("." == -1))
{
    alert("You must enter a valid Email address!\n"
}
```

I've tried changing the indexof check to different letters instead of the symbols, but it still returns -1, which makes me think I'm trying to get the data incorrectly.

Comment: it's custEmail.value.indexOf("@") == -1, not indexOf("@" == -1)

Comment: Oh my god I'm an idiot. I blame lack of sleep. This was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your parens are in the wrong place

```
custEmail.value.indexOf("@") == -1 || custEmail.value.indexOf(".") == -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 input type email rather than writing validations yourself

```
<input type="email"/>
```

Comment: This is more of a skills exercise than something that is supposed to be completely functional, which is why I wanted to do it manually.

Comment: Okay great, you also use regex to do validations like these as a part of skill development